# Codeigniter embedding swf

Tags: php, codeigniter, flash

I've searched the internet but I can't see a good tutorial on embedding swf in codeigniter. 
My questions are:

1. Is it possible to embed swfs in codeigniter?
   or just use html embedding?
2. Is Uploadify suitable for embedding?
3. Is there any tutorials for embedding swf in codeigniter?

Sorry im just new to codeigniter and php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably are not able to find a tutorial, because there's no such thing ;)
CodeIgniter uses a MVC (Model View Controller) structure. The View is (or can be) HTML.

So you don't embed it in CI but just use HTML. You could use CI to dynamically change the embedded SWF.

I don't understand the Uploadify part of your question. It's for file uploading...?
Hope this answers your questions.

ps.
Take a look at [netTuts](http://net.tutsplus.com/?s=codeigniter) for CI tutorials.